# How to align 3 images on a cover page

Tags: align

I'm a beginner on LaTeX.
I'm actually writting my internship report and I have a problem on the cover page.
I'm trying to align three images (logo) but i can't do it properly.
Here is the code :

```
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=3.5cm]{./image/Icb.png}
\hfill
\includegraphics[width=5cm]{./image/ubfc.png}
\hfill
\includegraphics[width=4.5cm]{./image/eiphi.png} \[3cm]
\hfil
\end{center}
```

And here is the result :
[image]

I want the images to be well aligned but they are offset and as soon as I change the size it gets worse.
I tried to search for answer on the internet i can't find a solution...
I have tried to use "minipage" or "figure" but I can't get the desired result.

Thank you in advance
JParize

Comment: It seems some of them contain excessive white space (you can wrap each image in `\fbox{....}` to see the white space. If you just want to align vertically, have a look at the tools in the `adjustbox` package.

Comment: You can wrap the `\includegraphics` commands into a `\raisebox` command to shift the image up- or downwards, like `\raisebox{2ex}{\includegraphics{..}}` will shift the image up by `2ex`.

Comment: Thank you for your answers ! The problem is solved !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}


\begin{document}


\begin{figure}[!htb]
\minipage{0.32\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{image.png}
\endminipage\hfill
\minipage{0.32\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{image.png}
\endminipage\hfill
\minipage{0.32\textwidth}%
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{image.png}
\endminipage
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It works ! Thank you very much !